# Create a drop-down list based on the unique values in the column and assign the selected value to the variable

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

I have a huge dataframe:

```
              df
 code_1     code_2    code_3
065.0055     3315      N-W
067.3355     4511      S-E
065.0055     3315      N-W
034.0035     4511      N-W
067.3355     1311      S-E
...
```

In the original dataframe, there are several columns and a large number of rows.

I need to find unique values in the columns `code_1`, `code_2`, `code_3`, then create a drop-down list and assign the selected value to a specific variable. And I need to do this for each column separately.

For example, I find all the unique values in a column `code_1` , the user selects the desired value from the drop-down list (for example `065.0055`) and this value is assigned to the variable(`vl = '065.0055'`).

I need to assign the chosen values to the variable, so that I can continue to make calculations based on them.

I found how to create a drop down list, but I do not know how to assign the selected value(as in the example with `vl`)

Here is my code:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
from IPython.html.widgets import interactive

items = ['-']+sorted(df['code_1'].unique().tolist())

def view(x=''):
    if x=='-':
        return df
    return df[df['code_1']==x]

w = widgets.Select(options=items)
interactive(view, x=w)
```

As a result, I need to get three variables, for example:
If the user made the following choice: from `code_1` was chosen `065.0055`, from `code_2` was chosen `3315`, from `code_3` was chosen `S-E`.

I need to get three variables

```
vl1 = '065.0055'
vl2 = '3315'
vl3 = 'S-E'
```

I need advice, please!

**UPD** After studying a few questions, I decided to try using `Tkinter`
Here is my code:

```
items = ['-']+sorted(df['code_1'].unique().tolist())
items1 = ['-']+sorted(df['code_2'].unique().tolist())
items2 = ['-']+sorted(df['code_3'].unique().tolist())

from tkinter import*

class MyOptionMenu(OptionMenu):
    def __init__(self, master, status, *options):
        self.var = StringVar(master)
        self.var.set(status)
        OptionMenu.__init__(self, master, self.var, *options)
        self.config(font=('calibri',(10)),bg='white',width=12)
        self['menu'].config(font=('calibri',(10)),bg='white')

root = Tk()
optionList = items
optionList1 = items1
optionList2 = items2
mymenu1 = MyOptionMenu(root, 'Select code_1', *optionList)
mymenu2 = MyOptionMenu(root, 'Select code_2', *optionList1)
mymenu3 = MyOptionMenu(root, 'Select code_3', *optionList2)
mymenu1.pack()
mymenu2.pack()
mymenu3.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

How can I save the result of the selection to a variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current selection of an `OptionMenu` is stored in its **[StringVar](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)**. You can get it using the StringVar's `.get()` method:

```
selection1 = mymenu1.var.get()
```

If you want to save all current selections for example when the user presses a button, you could add the following before `root.mainloop()`:

```
def save_selected_values():
    global values
    values = [mymenu1.var.get(), mymenu2.var.get(), mymenu3.var.get()]
    print(values)

button = Button(root, text="OK", command=save_selected_values)
button.pack()
```